# PHP What the meaning or use of echo << JS "some javascript code " JS;?

Tags: php

I need to know what is the actual use or the need to write a echo like below,

```
echo <<< JS

                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">      
                        function writeThisStatus (obj,id) {
                              writeStatus(obj,id,'OPTUS_COMP');
                              setBackground('row_'+id,(obj.checked ? 1 : 0));
                        }
                </script>

JS;
```

is this just equal to the normal echo " string "; or does something else ?

Comment: Look for `heredoc` in the manual.

Comment: That's a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)